# Is $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Is $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$

There must be a difference, or not ? which is equal to $(a,\infty)$ ? RHS must be open, since countable union of open sets is open, but what is LHS then ?

Comment: Yes, they are the same open set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equal. There is no difference. Both sets are equal to $(a, \infty)$. The only point of contention would be $a$ and it does not belong to any of the two sets.

Supose $x \in \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$. Then $x \in [a + \frac 1 m, \infty)$ for some $m \in \Bbb N$.

As long as you can picture that $[a + \frac 1 m, \infty) \subseteq (a+\frac{1}{m + 1},\infty)$ ( **EDIT:** this is because $\frac{1}{m} \gt \frac{1}{m + 1} \implies x \ge a + \frac{1}{m} \gt a + \frac{1}{m + 1}$) we have that $x \in (a+\frac{1}{m + 1},\infty) $ and hence $x \in \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$

Therefore $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},\infty) \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$$

Similarly since $ (a+\frac{1}{m'},\infty) \subseteq  [a+\frac{1}{m'},\infty)$ for $m' \in \Bbb N$ it can be shown that

$$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n},\infty) \supseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},\infty)$$

whence the equality follows.

Comment: Of course with 2 inclusions clear. but it looks weird.

Comment: It sure does. I personally have not grasped it properly either to be honest.

Comment: Note that only finite unions of closed sets are surely closed. This cannot be extended to countable unions. That is why LHS remains open. Since it is an infinite union.

Comment: Since it is a union, we can always find $m$, s.t. $[a+\frac{1}{m},\infty)\subset(a+\frac{1}{m+1},\infty)$But this is not valid for the Intersections,i.e. $(a,\infty)=\bigcap(a-\frac{1}{n},\infty)≠\bigcap[a-\frac{1}{n},\infty)=     [a,\infty)$ , right ?

Comment: LHS is equal to $(a - 1, \infty)$ and RHS is equal to $[a - 1, \infty)$ neither of which are equal to $[a, \infty)$. But don't worry I remember trying to answer a similar question and getting it wrong a million times.

Comment: but intersection, not union

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're the same

The LHS is open as well, and you can prove it by element membership.

It's clear that the LHS has to be a superset of the RHS (since it's a union of supersets of the RHS's sets). It remains to show that anything in the LHS is also in the RHS.

Take some $x\in \text{LHS}$. Then for some $k\in\mathbb{N}, x \geq a+\frac{1}{k}$. But then $x>a+\frac{1}{k+1}$, so then $x\in(a+\frac{1}{k+1},\infty)$, so then it's inside some set in the RHS! Then it must be in the union of all the sets in the RHS. That means that $\text{LHS}\subseteq \text{RHS}$.